# MathJax overarrow too short

Tags: symbols, mathjax

I am trying to place an overarrow over a piece of text in MathJax.
I am using a custom font that I declare in the code-
\(\overrightarrow{\style{font-family: mysans, TeX, Arial, sans-serif;}{\text{" + tString + "}}}\)"

It works ok for most letters- for capital W or M , using a couple in a row like "WWW" the overbar is too short.
For lowercase i , using a couple in a row, ie "iii" it is too long. My hunch is that MathJax is using a standard character width size to figure out the length of the overarrow and when the character is much longer or shorter than that size, it calculates the overarrow incorrectly. Is there any way around this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you generally cannot use custom fonts with MathJax. As [the documentation says](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/font-support.html)

> Since browsers do not provide APIs to access font metrics, MathJax has to ship with the necessary font data; this font data is generated during development and cannot be generated on the fly. In addition, most fonts do not cover the relevant characters for mathematical layout. Finally, some fonts (e.g. Cambria Math) store important glyphs outside the Unicode range, making them inaccessible to JavaScript.

However, if you are only looking to use custom fonts in text elements, then there is a way to work around this: style the surrounding context and set `mtextFontInherit:true` for the output jax, [cf. e.g. here for HTML-CSS](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/HTML-CSS.html).

Unfortunately, this won't actually help you right now. There's a minor regression in MathJax 2.5 (see [this discussion](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/pull/1065#issuecomment-75952922) leading to the result you describe). This will be fixed in 2.5.1 and in the mean time you could set `noReflows:false` for the HTML-CSS output.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect some new information.

Comment: A lot of the  spacing issues I was having seem to  have been fixed by the new version -  2.51 - which you mention above. It just came out a few hours ago. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: No problem. Bug reports are always welcome on our bug tracker. But as I wrote, hacking fonts like that is not supported so problems will arise.

Comment: One more question: I am trying to bring the overbars closer- I can use something like this to  facilitate vertical alignment: _stringOfHtml +=  "<span style='vertical-align:-10%'>" + "\\(\\overrightarrow{\\style{font-family:srasans, TeX, Arial, sans-serif;vertical-align:20%}{\\text{" + tString + "}}}\\)"+"</span>" I am afraid though this may lead to wacky results- is there a better way  to bring the overbars closer? Thanks!

Comment: Also- while the overbar fix works great for now getting an accurate line length on top, it does not work with exponents- ie exponents seemingly are not being calculated in the same way. I am having them hang over other characters, etc, when I use them. I looked at the actual div MathJax made- about 1/2 of the letter  W was sticking out.

Comment: Using \style this way is simply not supported. It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. I would suggest to make a new post and provide live examples.

Comment: I have opened a new question and posted examples- here they are as well: i cannot show live demo- with the vertical correction listed above: db.tt/HVmT736o then without the correction - overbars too high : db.tt/dBqrvgNx again, this is using a custom font which the client must have. –  user1700933 6 mins ago - called "Make overbars closer to numbers in MathJax"

Comment: I can only repeat. You cannot use MathJax with arbitrary fonts using \style it is inherently impossible to get reliable results.

Comment: OK- so getting rid of using style,  there any MathJax setting that would adjust the overbars? Or any other way you can think of? Thanks!